# readAudio -> cropAudio --> STFT == readAudio -> STFT -> cropAudio

Tags: audio, fft, wav

Is the following the same?

1. Read Audio file, then crop it to a certain frame length and perform a Short Time Fourier Transform on the excerpt

   *Code: stft(cropAudio(readAudio(wav)))*
2. Read Audio file, then perform the Short Time Fourier Transform on the whole Audio file and then crop the interesting part out

   *Code: cropAudio(stft(readAudio(wav)))*

The first option is much more efficient, since the STFT is only performed on a small part of the file - though I'm wondering if the results are the same.

Answer (score 2):

No they are not the same. In example 1 you are shortening the time domain waveform - reducing the duration of the signal. In example 2 the data that you are cropping is in the frequency domain so you are throwing away frequency information.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's right. The Short Time Fourier Transform leads to a time-frequency domain, so the crop also just affects the time domain if I crop on this axis.